# I don't know the syntax error in this xquery code

Tags: xquery

```
let $d := doc('mondial.xml')
let $airports := $d/mondial/airport
let $countries := $d/mondial/country

for $data1 in $countries
    let $count :=xs:integer("0")
    let $name :=$data1/name
    let $car_code :=$data1/@car_code
    for $data2 in $airports
        where $car_code = $data2/@country 
            $count:= $count+ 1
    where xs:integer($count)>25 
        return
            <country>
                <name>{data($name)}</name>
                <count>{data($count)}</count>
            </country>
```

This is my code, when I ran this code, there is syntax error:
error: syntax error, unexpected $[err:XPST0003]
$count:=$count+1

Comment: I provided an answer below that shows how to use the `at` syntax, but the more I look at your original XQuery the less clear it is what you are trying to count.  The nested for is not properly organized and you will just get more syntax errors.

Comment: So what do you want to achieve, count the airports in each country and return the count for those countries that have more than 25 airports?

Comment: Yes I wanted to get a list of countries with more than 25 airports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer

```
let $d := doc('mondial.xml')
let $airports := $d/mondial/airport
let $countries := $d/mondial/country
for $data1 in $countries
    let $name :=$data1/name
    let $car_code :=$data1/@car_code
    let $count := count($airports[@country eq $car_code])   
    where $count>25     
        return
            <country>
                <name>{data($name)}</name>
                <count>{data($count)}</count>
            </country>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
let $d := doc('mondial.xml')
let $airports := $d/mondial/airport
let $countries := $d/mondial/country

for $country in $countries
  let $airport-count := count($airports[@country = $country/@car_code])
where $airport-count > 25
return
  <country>
  {
     $country/name,
     <count>{$airport-count}</count>
  }
  </country>
```

Comment: Your answer is totaly right thank you for your help.